# Weird wording in the help documentation for answering questions

Tags: discussion, help-center

I was reading the help documentation on how to write good answers and came across this (emphasis mine)

> Pay it forward
>
> Saying “thanks” is appreciated, **but it doesn’t answer the question.** Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

The bolded part seems very weird to me. Yes, saying "thanks" doesn't answer a question, but "thanks" is usually said by the person who *asked* the question and wants to get it answered. I find this wording extremely weird, and was wondering if there was a reason for it or if it's an error.

As a side note, I think it's also strange that only up-voting, and not accepting, answers is mentioned.

Comment: It's also said by users who stumble upon the question later and find the answer useful. Users who are *not* the question author post thank you answers way, way more often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's great that it was obvious to you that saying, "thanks" doesn't answer the question.  Sadly, it's not obvious to lots of other people, who regularly post answers just to thank other people for answers that they've posted, hence the need for the help center to tell them not to.

As much as I wish saying this wasn't necessary, history has shown us that it is.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about this tendency of new users. This makes a lot more sense than what I had been considering.